# How can I package my Android app into an .apk?

Tags: android, apk

I need to email a coworker my android app as an .apk so that he can install & test it on his Samsung Galaxy Tab.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build .apk file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-apk-file)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Linux. CLI is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't distribute apk files that have not been signed.  Here are the official [instructions](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've looked through the documentation, but one thing remains unclear... My coworker is not a programmer, nor does he have the SDK installed on his computer. I need a simple way to give him the .apk so he can install it on his phone/tablet. Do I need to sign the .apk?

Comment: Yes, you yourself build and sign the apk following the steps in the link. Then you can just email the resulting apk to an account he can access from his phone.  As long as he has the setting to allow installs from unknown sources he should just be able to install from there.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done from the command line using something like:

```
$ cd project
$ android update project --path .
$ ant release
```

This requires:

- The Android SDK installed and the `tools` sub-directory in the path.
- Ant installed and in the path.

The result will be written into the `bin` sub-directory as '*project*-release.apk'.

Comment: I believe this would have worked, but the compilation process did not take my included libraries into account. (i.e. I got errors on every reference to my included libraries). Do you know of a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this question's answers to obtain the .apk itself: [How to build an APK file in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4600891/404469). If you've built the project (i.e. with Eclipse) it exists in the project's bin directory.

If your friend needs a way to install the .apk, using the SDK tools then connect your phone via USB and run `adb install appname.apk`. Without SDK tools, your friend could use an app like [Installer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/installer/com.rhythm.hexise.inst).