# How to make .apk file

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to build .apk file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-apk-file)

Please guide how to make .apk file . I have a knowledge that it is in bin directory and before it was working fine . Now when my application is completed and trying to make .apk file its just coming with 0.97 mb  although there are many images in it .when i try to install on phone  its says file not supported but directly from eclipse its get installed and work fine .my bin folder contain .dex and resource.ap_ also . Do i need to make them also . 
I have tried with [export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-apk-file) but it was also giving same error on the phone . please help .

Comment: Please check this link, best answer is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755447/how-to-export-an-apk-file-using-eclipse/23755448#23755448

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Eclipse, right-click on the project in Package Explorer, then under "Android Tools" choose "Export signed application package". There will be some UI regarding signing key generation/choice, you'll get a chance to provide file name, and then you'll get your APK where you want it.

If you're not using Eclipse, why not?

Answer (score 1):

If Eclipse isn't building a valid .apk file, try fixing the project properties. In the Package Explorer, right click on the project name, then select Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

Be aware that the .apk file generated in the bin/ directory is signed by a built-in debug signing certificate. This is okay for use in the emulator or in a device dedicated to testing, but for production use, you should sign the .apk with your own certificate. You do this by exporting the .apk as described by Seva. See the [guide topic on this subject](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) for details.