# How to make a application build in android (apk file)

Tags: android

Hi i'm new to android my client want to run the app in their on Android Device i go through the many answers through Stack overflow like this:-

[How to make .apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184132/how-to-make-apk-file)

[How to build an APK file in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-apk-file)

but i'm unable to make build.
I want to make a build of app in which is usually .apk extension and how i'm able to install this .apk file in my clients android device it doesn't have any eclipse or IDE.

Please suggest me the way or some links regarding this process to build and install the app in clients android device without using eclipse or any IDE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this link, best answer is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755447/how-to-export-an-apk-file-using-eclipse/23755448#23755448

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse create .apk file of your project by itself and save it in bin folder copy that apk file and send that to client and tell him to save apk on SD card and run directly from SD card. It will work.

Comment: Installing through the Gmail client is easier

Answer (score 0):

the moment you run the app on the emulator or a device, the .apk file is created and put in /%YOUR PROJECT%/bin/app.apk

you can send that to your client...