# How to create apk file for android?

Tags: android

I wrote some android application using Eclipse. 
I found apk file in the bin directory.

When i connect USB cable between the cell phone and the computer - the application is running. 
But when i disconnect the USB cable from the cell phone - and i trying to launch the application from the cell phone i get message

```
        "Waiting for debugger" 
        "Application ( process name .. ) is waiting for the debugger to attach"
```

So, How can i create apk ( installation file ) for using with no debug ?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-apk-file

Comment: And please use search before asking, this is common question.

Comment: Please check this link, best answer is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755447/how-to-export-an-apk-file-using-eclipse/23755448#23755448

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a Debug.waitForDebugger() somewhere in your code?

Here are some tricks...
 http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/bdf61367c8649f4a?pli=1

Seen some indication that there is a global debug flag in the phone that might have got stucked restarting the phone might help.

Answer (score 6):

If you like to release your app to the public, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) you can find step by step info on how to do it.

Include how to create the apk file, from the link:

To create a signed and aligned .apk in Eclipse:

1. Select the project in the Package Explorer and select File > Export.
2. Open the Android folder, select Export Android Application, and click Next.
   The Export Android Application wizard now starts, which will guide you through the process of signing your application, including steps for selecting the private key with which to sign the .apk (or creating a new keystore and private key).
3. Complete the Export Wizard and your application will be compiled, signed, aligned, and ready for distribution.

Answer (score 2):

File - Export - Android Application

Answer (score 1):

Android application package file (APK) is
program binary used to distribute and install
Android application onto the Android operating
system. Here we'll see step by step procedure
of creating .apk file ready to be installed in
Android device.

Tools & Technologies used in this article :
1. JDK 1.6
2. Eclipse 3.7
3. Android SDK

There are two ways to export Aplication
Package in Eclipse using Android Tools
1. Export Unsigned Application Package
2. Export Signed Application Package

1. Export Unsigned Application Package
   Right click on the Android project (say
   'AndroidHello') and from the context menu
   select Android Tools --> Export Unsigned
   Appliaction Package . Browse the location to
   save the apk and click Save button. Click Ok
   button in the following window to proceed.
2. Export Signed Application Package
   Right click on the Android project (say
   'AndroidHello') and from the context menu
   select Android Tools --> Export Signed
   Appliaction Package . Select the project to
   export and Click Next button.