# How to Export an APK file using Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

There are two ways to export Application Package in Eclipse using Android Tools -

1. Export Unsigned Application Package
2. Export Signed Application Package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps of generating an APK file using Eclipse -

- Go to **File > Export**

[image]

- From the Export window, go to **Android > Export Android Application**.

[image]

- Click **Browse...** and select the Android Application project to Export.

[image]

- Click Browse and select the debug.keystore. The default location for debug.key store on OSX is "**/Users//.android/debug.keystore**" and the password is "**android**". When you're ready to release your app to an application marketplace, you should use an existing keystore or create a new keystore.

[image]

- Select the "**androiddebugkey**" alias and use "**android**" as the password.

[image]

- Select a destination for the APK file and click **Finish**.

[image]

- Now you are ready to upload and distribute the APK.

Source - [Test flight](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1279844-how-to-create-an-apk-adt-bundle)