# How to run an Android app which will run in any system without using Eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ndk

I have created an Android Calculator app in Eclipse.  If I want to run my app I need run it through Eclipse. But I want to run my app without Eclipse in any system as normal apps run, just download it and run.

If any one knows how to do this, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take the .apk file in your bin folder. This file is your entire app packaged together.

You can run & install this on other Android phones, but they will have to have enabled "unknown sources" in application settings.

Otherwise, you'll have to publish to the app store, from where the entire world that owns an Android device can download it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Inside **bin** folder of your `Calculator app` project located on Hard disk there will be **.apk** file which you can transfer to your device then open **file browser** whichever you have that will allow you to install and run your application cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
app run without eclipse in any system as a normal apps run
```

may I know how the normal apps run?

it need any emulator or device.

you can run the .apk file without eclipse also!.

download the Android SDk and create an emulator thru avd command and install any app.

the other way you can do by 3rd party software called **BlueStacks App Player**

this software is only for mac and Windows [download here](http://bluestacks.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to install it on any device from your system, without the need to run Eclipse?

The command would be something like "adb install bin/MyCalculator.apk".  Once you do that, your app is installed just like any other.

Do you mean you want *anybody* to install your app on their device?  Your best bet is to just put it on the Android Market.  Don't forget to generate a real signing key (don't use the Eclipse debug key) and sign your app properly before uploading it to the market.

If you don't want to use the market, then you can put the apk file on any web page, and have people download it with their browser.  Then they go to their device settings and enable "Unknown sources".  After that, they can run their browser, go to "Menu > Download" and select the apk they just downloaded.

Or, you can send the apk file to someone directly, and have them attach their device to their computer, enable USB, and copy the apk to their /sdcard directory somewhere.  Then they launch a file browser (they'll have to install that first) and navigate to the apk file.  I *think* that will allow them to install the apk on their device.

I think that should cover it.

Answer (score -1):

You should generate the .apk file, and install it on any device you want..
http://www.technobitez.com/how-to/create-apk-files-for-android-phone
[How to build an APK file in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-apk-file)