# How to run simple android app on my phone?

Tags: android, smartphone

I wrote a simple application for android, it works fine on my phone, but i want to run it on my phone without connecting my phone to the computer, i mean i want to install the application on my computer. How can i do this? Also what if i want to send this app to a frind? Do i have to install it to market?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is create an .apk file.
Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-apk-file) about creating it.

You can then put it on the play store, or upload the .apk to a server and use the URL to download it.

Or you could just copy the .apk from your computer onto your phone then just click the file and it will install.

Using anything other than the market will require the user to 'allow applications from unknown sources'.

Comment: Thanks, so if i transfer that apk file to my phone, will it work?

Comment: Yes it will, just locate it and click on it.

Answer (score 1):

After you will run for the first time the application on the phone (launched from the computer), it will remain installed after you disconnect the phone from the computer.

Then you can launch it from the Applications menu.

Comment: thanks, but actually, i want to send it to a friend and want to run on another phone. How can i do that?

Comment: in `/bin` directory you will find an `.apk` file after you run the application. Send that file to your friend and after he copies the file on his phone will be able to launch the application.

Answer (score 1):

Preinstalled applications are in `/system/app` folder. User installed applications are in `/data/app`. I guess you can't access unless you have a rooted phone. Try to carry with your external memory card.

**If you want to reach your .apk file simply try below...**

I assumed you are using Eclipse..

in `/bin` folder of your project you can see `appName.apk` then copy and send it to your friend.

Answer (score 0):

If you use eclipse you need to do a right click on the project folder. 
 
There you have the menu for android tools. 
There you must click the export (un)signed application package button and then a wizard opens where you have to do some settings. (I prefer sigend one). 
There you need to create a new keystore and a new certificate. It does not really matter what you insert there. 
 
After you created these files you can save an "apk" and copy it to your device. 
There you simply have to open the apk and the app will be installed. 
But I don't know how to install the app on your pc. I just know that you can run an emulator and install it there (bluestack is the emulators' name).