# Eclipse android doesn't generate apk

Tags: android, eclipse

On eclipse Juno for Windows 64 bit I got an error couldn't find ....APK. I tried all the answers on this link [How to build an APK file in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-apk-file) to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I went to the SDK manager and updated. The problem was evidently fixed.

Comment: Asked and answered in 2 minutes - got to be a record

Comment: I knew the answer and wanted it on record to save people time