# Where is my apk file for my android application? (via eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

Where is my apk file? I have made an app and a library project that it depends on. It loads in the emulator fine...

But there is no .apk file in bin/

Isn't this where it's supposed to be?

Comment: "Isn't this where it's supposed to be?" -- if by "/bin" you mean the `bin/` directory of your project, that is where your APK will reside when compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apk should be found under `bin/` folder. Make sure you compile, and not just build the 
project: [How to build an APK file in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-apk-file?rq=1)

**EDIT** As Chris kindly pointed out, `bin/` is generally found under your project directory, e.g. `path/to/projectdir/bin`

Comment: That's not quite a correct statement of the path.  "/bin" is a folder just below the root of the filesystem, which is almost definitely not the case.  What you mean is something such as "project_dir/bin" often casually expressed as "bin/"

Comment: Yes, @ChrisStratton, that was a typo. Fixed answer as per your suggestion

Comment: Apparently I needed to build it manually first...

Answer (score 0):

> I have made an app and a library project that depends on it

The apk is only generated if you are making an app. As far as I know, projects marked as library don't generate the apk.

Maybe you can generate it manually by exporting the project as an Android application.

Comment: My wording was confusing. I fixed it above. I don't want the apk for the library project.