# Got "Keystore was tampered" error After I changed the package name. How to fix?

Tags: android, keystore, code-signing-certificate

I a signed my appication with a new certificate and set password.
When I tried to upload a beta version of my app to Developer Console (google play).
An error message appear asked me to change my package name because the default com.example.xxx is not allowed.
I changed the package name. but after that when I try to build and run my app. I get the following error.

> Error generating final archive: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Any Ideas?

Comment: After changing package name you will have to create a keystore and sign your app with this key again. Then upload this apk in Google play again. Hope its work

Comment: This is the 1st time I do this. the app is signed automatically with a keystore every time I build (default: debug.keystore). what I did is signing it with certificate. now I have to sign it to a new keystore then to sign it with new certificate. is that right? if yes, I did create a new keystore how to sign it. I can't change the value in the "default debug keystore" in the preferences. what to do?

Comment: What is the default keystore name eclipse sign to my app?

Comment: You will have to create your own keystore.  If you are using the Eclipse plugin.

Right click on the project > Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package

Follow the instructions for creating a .keystore file and you're sorted!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-apk-file

Comment: Did that. and managed to upload an app version to developer console. The problem now is the compilation error.