# How can I save my Android application so that the end-user can execute it without the Android SDK

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, save

I have recently started programming for the Android platform. I have a simple application which I would like to email to someone so that they can execute the application and check how it works.

I am currently using the Emulator in the Android SDK to execute my application but the person who I am emailing it to does not have Android SDK and it would be a mission to send the whole project folder.

Is there any way that I can send just one file such as an .exe or something that would allow the recipient to execute the application to see how it works.

Thanks so much for your help in advance guys

Comment: You don't know that an Android application is packaged as an APK?

Comment: @Riga Kdot when u runs ur app it will generate .apk and u can send it to ur client for testing.

Comment: I think the issue is that he has the .apk, but the end user has nothing to install it on. I think he's looking for a standalone emulator/remote viewer

Comment: Hi everyone, when I run it, where is the .apk file saved? Sorry to be such a pain

Comment: In the "bin" folder in your project path you will have a <projectname>.apk that you can share with your clients. If they execute it in an Android mobile phone the application will be installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "exe" for android is called apk. I suggest you to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-apk-file) question. You'll need to build the apk and sign it in order to be able to run it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to send it to a user for testing purposes, you can enable the setting in the target android device to allow "unknown sources" (I don't know the proper english name, as I don't have an english android here at the moment). You can find this in the app settings.

In your development environment look for the `apk` file created by eclipse. Then connect your smartphone to the pc and copy the apk over. Start up a file manager and click on the apk and it will install just like any other app.

If you want to deploy it properly, you have to sign it and probably follow the procedures from google. Since I don't have a fully deployable app yet, I can't say what the procedures is for that, but the google site is very helpfull on all aspects about android programming.

Answer (score 1):

Check the "bin" folder in your project path. There you will have a .apk that you can share with your clients.

If they execute it in an Android mobile phone the application will be installed.