# how to export android code

Tags: android, eclipse

there.

I noticed that samples on Google developers page can be imported on "Existing Android Code Into Workspace" menu on eclipse, not "Existing Projects into Workspace". I wonder how I can export my project as android code like the samples. I tried to find out that feature on eclipse but failed. Can you tell me how to do it please? And what is good to export as android code not existing projects?

Comment: have you want export code?not apk file right?

Comment: yes, i want to export code as android code not apk or general project.

Answer (score 0):

by this step in your **ADT**,you will get your `project` as a **Zip** file.

```
Right-click, Export -> General, Archive File -> Next -> provide the output path -> Finish.
```

to get as a apk then try this step

```
Export -> Android -> Export Android Application -> 
    YOUR_PROJECT_NAME ->
     Create new key store path -> Fill the detail -> Set the .apk location -> Now you can get your .apk file
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export to `apk` file. Refer here : [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-apk-file-in-eclipse)