# How to only build and generate apk by using the Eclipse Android ADT?

Tags: android, apk, adt, eclipse-adt

I do not want to run the application because the emulator takes too much time to start and showing the app , so I want to know how to build and generate the apk of an application with the Eclipse Android ADT.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-an-apk-file-in-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..

right click on the project you want the apk for, then Android Tools will lead to the Exporting the apk file. You have to create a key one time and you can use it further in your apk generation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Genymotion Emulator. It is really fast. http://www.genymotion.com/

I use it since a half year. The emulator ist faster and better than the normal Android Emulator.