# "Run as Android Application" doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

I installed the ADT (Android Developer Tools) plugins for eclipse and directed it to the correct Android APK files. I also have Android Virtual Device set up.

Nothing happens when I click "run as android application," but my AVD runs fine and is actually very responsive.

This is all Java in eclipse by the way.

[image]

Right click the pic, and open it in a new tab to see the larger version.

EDIT: Fixed, all I had to do was click run dropdown menu on eclipse, then click run again :)

Comment: Please, note that there's no beginner, intermediate, advanced nor any other level here in the site. You ask as a professional, you get an answer from another professional.

Comment: You directed Eclipse to the correct Android APK files?? You shouldn't have to do that. Eclipse needs the original files for it to generate its own APK. Please try creating from scratch a blank "hello world" android project from Eclipse and try to see if that will run. Also, make sure to close any unrelated project to the one you're trying to run. And look in the Problems View of Eclipse to see if they are any errors there.

Comment: I'm reading off a "android beginners" book, it told me to download the Android APK directory, so I did and directed ADT to my APK directory, which it accepted. The blank "hello world" is exactly what I'm trying to run.

Comment: *Android SDK directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing it manually to see if adb is working. This is time consuming, but is a workaround. See this page on how to do that: [How to build an APK file in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-an-apk-file-in-eclipse)

**How to install an .apk file on the emulator:**

Start the console Run (Windows + R) then type cmd, and move to the platform-tools folder of SDK directory. this is located wherever you've placed the adt folder.

Paste the APK file in the platform-tools folder.

Then type the following command: adb install example.apk

Modify example.apk to the name of the apk you've chosen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, it already had the intent filters. I've attached a screenshot of my entire eclipse window right before i click "run as".

Comment: Have you tried compiling the apk? If that works, then there's a problem with adb/eclipse, otherwise it's your app. Then we can narrow down the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea how to compile the apk. If you want to zoom in on the screenshot, just right click, open in new tab.

Comment: See this article for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-an-apk-file-in-eclipse

Then I can narrow down the problem/give you a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the article: I built the APK file. How do I compile it specifically? Sorry that you have to walk me through this, I'm really new to Android Development.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a tutorial. Also, if you've built the .apk file, it's already compiled, all you need to do is install it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I may have the wrong APK's.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to ask if you still have a problem.

Comment: Fixed, all I had to do was click Run in the dropdown Eclipse menu, then click Run again :)