# How to send my project APK through email for testing?

Tags: android

I need to send my Android project APK through email. Do I just need to copy APK file from bin folder and send it in email so that they can test my project or is there any other process?

Comment: there is no any other process! just if its in debug mode your codes totally accessible and it can be decompile easily

Comment: yes you are right user3337747 but before sending apk just build and run your project

Comment: Is that one apk file enough to run the project on phone?

Comment: yes android apps just run on apk,every reference library will include inside that automatically,apk is a package just like Rar or zip

Comment: try to export your apk

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build an APK file in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-an-apk-file-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Sending the APK through email is perfectly fine. All you need to do is note where you download it.

Also before you can actually install the APK file, you’ll need to tell your device that it can install any apps outside of the Play Store without throwing a fit. You can find this switch in your Settings –> Security –> Unknown Sources.

Once this is enabled, you’re clear to fire up your file browser, locate the APK file, and open it. The Android OS should take over, identifying that the APK file is an app, and ask you whether you’d like to go ahead and install it, all permissions accounted for. That should be it.