# how can I import project as *.APK file in my Android phone?

Tags: android, apk

I have created one project for android phone,  how can i import project as APK file for android or is there any other way to make installation file...plz

Comment: In Android Studio: "Build -> Generate Signed APK"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build an APK file in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-an-apk-file-in-eclipse)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Try hope it wil help
```

Export -> Android -> Export Android Application -> YOUR_PROJECT_NAME -> Create new key store path -> Fill the detail -> Set the .apk location -> Now you can get your .apk file

Comment: Note: that's the debug apk