# Save android application to device when running

Tags: android, eclipse, device

How do I download my android application to device to run again when I'm not running from Eclipse?

Currently it runs on the tablet, but once finished it isn't on the device.

Comment: post your manifest, did you add the proper `<intent-filter>` for the main activity? (LAUNCHER and MAIN)? because once you run the app from eclipse it's already installed, if you can't find it in the applications drawer of the mobile, then the above might be wrong in ur manifest

Answer (score 0):

So when you start the app to run into your device not in the emulator than the app would be installed like you install from other sources or playstore and when you unplug your phone or tablet the app is installed normal in your rom !

Ps: in your mainiafest check this :
android:debuggable
Whether or not the application can be debugged, even when running on a device in user mode — "true" if it can be, and "false" if not. The default value is "false".

Answer (score 0):

> When you run the project on the emulator, the APK file is generated in the ***bin*** directory. Keep in mind that just building the project (and not running it) will not output the APK file into the bin directory.

from:[How to build an APK file in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600891/how-to-build-an-apk-file-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Get the apk from Eclipse bin folder and install the app from there. Also can I recommend you to switch to Android Studio?